# Number of sample units to have a given probability that the sample mean is less than a value

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Would this be the correct approach to finding $n$ if I want the sample mean to be less than $5.7$ with a probability of $95\%$? ( Given $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu=6,\,\sigma^{2}=0.3^{2})$ )

$Pr(\bar{X}<5.7)=0.95$

$Pr\left(z<\frac{5.7-6}{0.3/\sqrt{n}}\right)=0.95$

$\frac{5.7-6}{0.3/\sqrt{n}}=1.65$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*I think you have it backwards.* If the population mean is $\mu = 6,$ then it
will be difficult for the mean of a large-ish sample to be *less* than $5.7.$ **In your
formulation it will require a *negative* z-value to match the negative quantity $\frac{5.7-6}{0.3/\sqrt{n}}.$**

If you want the sample mean of $n$ observations to be ***more*** than 5.7 about 95% of the time, then you have $-1.645 = \frac{5.7-6}{0.3/\sqrt{n}}.$
And, solving for $n$ we get $n \approx 1.645^2 = 2.7055,$ so $n =3$
observations should suffice.

---

*Note:* In case you are still having trouble with the intuition of this, here is a simulation in R statistical software with $m = 10^6$
samples of size $n,$ one sample of size $n = 3$ on each row of the matrix.
Of the one million sample averages `a` simulated in this way, almost 96% *exceeded* $5.7.$ (Being slightly fussier about the simulation result, the expected proportion of averages *exceeding* $5.7$ is about $0.95807 \pm 0.00040.$)

```
m = 10^6;  n = 3
x = rnorm(m*n, 6, .3)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=m)
a = rowMeans(MAT)
mean(a > 5.7)
## 0.95807             # simulated value
2*sd(a > 5.7)/sqrt(m)
## 0.0004008587        # 95% margin of simulation error

1-pnorm(5.7, 6, .3/sqrt(3))
## 0.9583677           # exact probability
```

In the figure below the histogram shows the simulated sample means, the
curve is the density function of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=6, \sigma = .3/\sqrt{3}),$
and the area under the density curve to the *right* of the vertical dotted line
is about 0.958.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The only problem is that I'm sure I'm asked to find an n such that the probability of the mean to be **less** than 5.7 is 95%. This, given the equation, should result impossible, am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I can make no sense of your question as posed. Probably it's a typo or mistake. Is there someone to ask? Or maybe change 5.7 to something like 6.3 if $\mu = 6.0.$ In my answer, key statement put into **bold type.**